# How can I manually add/adjust login&password to Chrome password manager?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

We use multistep sign-in flow that redirects to organization sign-in page and then back. By doing that, chrome doesn't ask to save login&password. Is there a way to manually add or adjust the login&password pair in chrome password manager?

The site in question is **not** blacklisted in *Never Saved* of `chrome://settings/passwords`.

PS: Strangely enough, chrome is suggesting me few logins I used in a different company some 5 years ago, maybe back then the flow was little different. This is why I would also accept a way to adjust such a pair if it were easier.

Comment: This has been proposed to Chrome https://www.chromestory.com/2018/06/chrome-save-password-manually/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work around it by manually adding an `<input type="password"/>` while on the intermediary page, then I submitted it which prompted me to save the password .

1. Right click the login field and choose **Inspect** or open Dev Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>).
   [image]
2. Locate the closest input, hover over it with mouse, it will highlight the correct element.
   [image]
3. Click on the input and press F2. Add new line at the end with `<input type="password/>` and confirm with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.
   [image]
4. Now notice the new password field. Enter your login and password and when you confirm, browser will prompt you to save the password.
   [image]

Comment: Where did you add this? how did you do it :)

Comment: @Topde I updated the answer with a detailed guide.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Oh not sure if I miss read the question, in my case there's a password field already but my org has disabled the option for chrome to suggest saving passwords so I'm stuck with the passwords I had saved before the policy change and can't add anymore. I just realised this when I tried your solution and it didn't work

Comment: So basically my org hasn't disabled chrome passwords, I can still use it just not save new ones

Comment: @Topde I am not sure how that policy is enforced (chrome profile, systemwide, mail account), but could you perhaps try using different account in chrome and add the login from another PC? The passwords should synchronize.

Comment: I thought about that but sync is disabled :(

Comment: @Topde Yeah I guess the only option left is to quit and find better workplace. Sorry. Or not. You can only gain.

Comment: Not going to lie I am fully considering that, the amount of awkward rules in place is ridiculous. I can't even get a proper IDE for development.

Comment: I have to use 4 different systems on a daily basis, passwords need to be 15+ chrs and I'm not allowed autofill at all, have to use this separate software where I need to open and copy paste the password

Comment: oh and everything logs me out after 1hr inactivity 

Comment: @Topde Bruh, what are you still doing at that company

Comment: applying for other jobs obvs